# What's the meaning of "the notice of the fair" and how do I understand "he had still at intervals a kind listener..."?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> With such rivals for **the notice of the fair** as Mr. Wickham and the
>   officers, Mr. Collins seemed to sink into insignificance; to the young
>   ladies he certainly was nothing; but he had still **at intervals a kind
>   listener** in Mrs. Phillips, and was by her watchfulness, most abundantly
>   supplied with coffee and muffin. ——— Pride and Prejudice

Besides, why is it "**in** Mrs. Phillips"? What's "by" in "by her watchfulness"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"The fair" there refers to young women. It is an adjective used nominally to refer to a class of beings.

The men strive, as rivals, to be noticed by the young women.  "The *notice* of the fair" refers to the **attention** of the fair.

> He had still at intervals a kind listener in Mrs Phillips.

**at intervals** means "periodically".

> He had still, periodically, a kind listener in Mrs Phillips.

Every now and then he would speak to Mrs Phillips and she was willing to listen to what he had to say.

**in** refers to the person in terms of their fulfilling a role or meeting a requirement. The role is found either in an antecedent or postcedent position, depending on where the prepositional phrase is placed:

> Boris Spassky had an able *opponent* **in** Bobby Fischer
>
> **In** Bobby Fischer, Boris Spassky had an able *opponent*.
>
> Acme Widgets had an able *CEO* **in** Mr. John Desmond.
>
> He had a kind *listener* **in** Mrs Phillips.

The **-er** suffix in *listener* refers to the noun as role/occupation, one whose job or role is to listen.

The object of **in** can be other than a person; a thing or action can also fulfill a role or satisfy a requirement:

> **In** driving recklessly, he had given the police *probable cause* to search his vehicle.
>
> **In** passing the Bar Exam, you have met the requirements for practicing law in the State of New Jersey.

The object of **in** has an *inherent quality* by virtue of which it fulfills a role or meets a requirement.